# Are there standard names for the ends of a homotopy?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, homotopy-theory, convention

In my mind, homotopies have a beginning and an end, a directionality, it is always from something to something.

Are there standard names for these in the literature? Can ppl be expected to understand if I write "the end of the homotopy $h$ is..."?

Comment: Are you referring to the maps given by $x \mapsto H(x,0)$ and $x \mapsto H(x,1)$?

Comment: @CliveNewstead yes

Comment: Begining/end maps. Time $0$/ time $1$ maps. etc... I think people will understand what you mean by 'end' of the homotopy, although as you point out... *which* 'end'?

Comment: Usually one writes something like $h:X \times I \ Y$ is a homotopy between $f$ and $g$ (or from $f$ to $g$). I don't think there is a standard name for it, but people will understand what you mean. Most often, instead of giving it a name most authors simply write what they would mean by this name, i.e. $h(\cdot,0)=f$ or $h_0=f$, where $h_t$ denotes the map $x \mapsto h(x,t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ronald Brown, [*Topology and Groupoids*](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) (2006), p.225:

> Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces. A map $F \colon X \times [0, q] \to Y$ will be called a
>   *homotopy of length* $q;$ for such $F,$ the *initial map* and the *final map* of $F$ are
>   respectively the functions
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> f \colon X & \to Y \\
> x & \mapsto F(x, 0)
> \end{aligned}
> \qquad
> \begin{aligned}
> g \colon X & \to Y \\
> x & \mapsto F(x, q).
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   We say $F$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$, and we write
>   $$
> F \colon f \simeq g.
> $$

Comment: The corresponding passage on page 192 of the first edition of Prof. Brown's book, published in 1968 under the title *Elements of Modern Topology,* differs from the later edition only in that it uses a different symbol for "maps to".

At the very least, these citations suggest (although they do not prove) that no *other* terms for these concepts were in common use, either in 1968 or in 2006. (On the other hand, I haven't found any evidence of these terms having caught on, although they are natural ones to use.)